# How do I determine a device's default orientation?

Tags: android, input, orientation, axis

I am developing a game with accelerometer controls. This works well on all the *mobile phones* I've tested it on. However, when testing on a *tablet*, the y and x axes are reversed, presumably because the device's default orientation is landscape.

How can I identify the default orientation of the device, to set my axes accordingly?

(I'm using Android SDK 1.5 - 1.7.)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the best way to do this is to check the screen size on the device and base a boolean  conditional to device on which axis to use. This is tested and working great.

> // Check the screen layout to determine if the device is a tablet.

```
public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
    boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    return (xlarge || large);
}
```

> // Changle Accelx or Accely input based on the above (Im using
>   OpenGLES 1.1)

```
if (isTablet(glGame)) {
    world.update(deltaTime, game.getInput().getAccelX());
}
if (!isTablet(glGame)) {
    world.update(deltaTime, game.getInput().getAccelY());
}
```